# If $x = A(BC-D)+BE$, then how to express $A(BC-D)+(B-F)E$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is probably a very simple question to answer for most people here, but I just don't see it, so hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a formula which looks like this:
$$x = A(BC-D)+BE.$$
Now, while the value of $x$ remains the same, this happens:
$$? = A(BC-D)+(B-F)E.$$

What expression in $x$ should go on the left side now?

Thanks!

Comment: Where this $F$ comes from?

Comment: You just subtracted $FE$.

Comment: FYI: It's unusual to use a whole bunch of capital letters to represent numerical variables. Most of the time, capital letters are used for other things, like geometrical points, sets, classes, etc. Sometimes, you might use a capital letter for a variable name to suggest a relationship with another variable with the same name in lower case. This is purely a matter of convention, but following convention tends to make it easier for other people to see what you mean immediately.

Comment: When I see something like $BC$, for example, I tend to think "the line segment between point $B$ and point $C$" or "the length of the line segment between point $B$ and point $C$".

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks I'll remember that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's call the result $x_{\text{new}}$. We have
$$x_{\text{new}}=A(BC-D)+(B-F)E.$$
Applying the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property), we know that
$$(B-F)E=BE-FE.$$
Thus
$$x_{\text{new}}=A(BC-D)+BE-FE.$$
We can see the original $x$ in there:
$$x_{\text{new}}=\underbrace{A(BC-D)+BE}_{x}-FE.$$
Thus, we can write $x_{\text{new}}$ in terms of $x$ as
$$x_{\text{new}}=x-FE.$$

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Working backwards, it seems like this is what happened. Start by subtracting $FE$ from both sides of the equation:
$$
x-FE = A(BC-D)+BE-FE
$$
Then factor out the $E$ from the last two terms:
$$
x-FE = A(BC-D)+(B-F)E
$$

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We start with

$$x=A(BC-D)+BE;$$

adding the quantity $-FE$ to both sides we arrive at

$$x-FE=A(BC-D)+BE-FE=A(BC-D)+(B-F)E.$$

In other words, **both** sides of your equation are shifted by the quantity $-FE$: in this sense, $x$ does not remain the same.